# How to rename datetime column name to string format in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset that has column names in datetime format:
[image]

And I would like to change their names to 2014-01-01 00:00:00 > Jan-14 and so on.

```
operations.columns = pd.to_datetime(operations.columns).to_period('M')
```

The above code gave me the following error:

**ParserError: Unknown string format: Aircraft Name**
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: `operations.columns[2:]` would give all the remaining columns.

Comment: gives me the following error > ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 14 elements, new values have 12 elements

Comment: You now get the length mismatch because `len(operations.columns) == 14`, and `len(operations.columns[2:]) == 12`. Try using a list comprehension: `operations.columns = [x.to_period('M') if type(x) is pd.Timestamp else x for x in operations.columns]`

Comment: @ouroboros1 it does not change the names still in 2014-01-01 00:00:00 format

Comment: If the values (Aircraft Name, Aircraft Type) are unique for every row, you might consider setting those as the index, and then all your columns with be datetimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to change it. Check if the column type is datetime, then reformat it otherwise, keep it as is

```
import datetime

operations.columns = [col.strftime('%M %d') 
               if (isinstance(col, datetime.date)  )
               else col
               for col in operations.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the column names to datetime (and format to the desired format), then use only those elements where the conversion succeeds (else use the old elements). EX:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 2], '2021-02-22 00:00:00': [3, 3, 3]})

newnames = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce').strftime("%b-%d")

df.columns = newnames.where(~newnames.isnull(), df.columns)

df
   a  b  Feb-22
0  1  2       3
1  1  2       3
2  1  2       3
```